# Sort pandas dataframe by customize way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tried a lot to sort DataFrame column on my own way. But could not be able to correctly do it. So refer given code and let me know what is the additional syntax to do the job.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TC': {0: '1-1.1', 1: '1-1.2', 2: '1-10.1', 3: '1-10.2', 4: '1-2.1', 5: '1-2.1', 6: '1-2.2', 7: '1-20.1', 8: '1-20.2', 9: '1-3.1'}, 'Case': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G', 7: 'H', 8: 'I', 9: 'J'}})
df.sort_values(["TC"], ascending=[True])
print (df)
```

This code does not give desire output. I need the Dataframe sorted as per below.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the numbers and form a `tuple`, then sort that `series` and use its `index` to `reindex` your original DataFrame.

```
>>> df.reindex(
        df['TC'].str.extractall('(\d+)')
                .unstack().astype(int)
                .agg(tuple, 1).sort_values()
                .index
    )

       TC Case
0   1-1.1    A
1   1-1.2    B
4   1-2.1    E
5   1-2.1    F
6   1-2.2    G
9   1-3.1    J
2  1-10.1    C
3  1-10.2    D
7  1-20.1    H
8  1-20.2    I
```

You can also use the `key` argument in `sort_values`:

```
>>> df.sort_values('TC', 
        key=lambda ser:
           ser.str.extractall('(\d+)')
              .unstack()
              .astype(int).agg(tuple, 1)
    )
```

If there are always three parts to an `ID` you can use `Series.str.split` on `non-numeric` characters with `expand=True`, instead of `extractall`, hence removing the need to use `unstack`:

```
>>> df.sort_values('TC', 
         key=lambda series:
             series.str.split(r'\D+', expand=True)
                   .astype(int).agg(tuple,1)
    )
```

Timings:

```
>>> %timeit df.reindex(df['TC'].str.extractall('(\d+)').unstack().astype(int).agg(tuple, 1).sort_values().index)
2.95 ms ± 40.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit df.sort_values('TC', key=lambda ser: ser.str.extractall('(\d+)').unstack().astype(int).agg(tuple, 1))
2.91 ms ± 32.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit df.sort_values('TC', key=lambda series:series.str.split(r'\D+', expand=True).astype(int).agg(tuple,1))
1.6 ms ± 5.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it this way. I think this would be faster.

```
df["range"] = df["TC"].apply(lambda x: [float(y) for y in x.split("-")])
df = df.sort_values(["range"], ascending=True).drop(["range"], axis="columns")
```

EDITED:
And since you asked for the case where the format of the range as 1_1_2 in place of 1-1.2 I would have done it this way:

```
df["range"] = df["TC"].apply(lambda x: tuple(x.split("_")))
df["range"] = df["range"].apply(lambda x: [float(x[0]), float("{}.{}".format(x[1], x[2]))])
df = df.sort_values(["range"], ascending=True).drop(["range"], axis="columns")
```

Comment: You made it Simple, What should the code if the data has in form of "1_2_1" instead of "1-2.1"

Comment: Well, it was not the case, still, I would have had an extra line of code to parse the column to required format as added in the edited section

Answer (score 0):

I have made one sort() function which will solve your query.

```html
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'TC': {0: '1-1.1', 1: '1-1.2', 2: '1-10.1', 3: '1-10.2', 4: '1-2.1', 5: '1-2.1', 6: '1-2.2', 7: '1-20.1', 8: '1-20.2', 9: '1-3.1'}, 'Case': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G', 7: 'H', 8: 'I', 9: 'J'}})


def sort(df):
    listTC=[]
    for i in df['TC']:
        listTC.append(float(i[2:]))
        
    df1=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(listTC,list(df['Case']))),columns=['TC','Case'])
    
    df_f=df1.sort_values(by=['TC'])
    
    listTC_final=[]
    for i in df_f['TC']:
        listTC_final.append('1-'+str(i))
        
    df_Final=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(listTC_final,list(df_f['Case']))),columns=['TC','Case'])
    
    return df_Final

print(sort(df))
```

Still if any questions let me know.
Thanks